# MongoDB - Maximum file size using GridFS

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

I am wondering what is the maximum file size if someone wants to store a file using the GridFS? I can't find any information so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Infinity basically, or a more exact number would be how much your working set allows.

The GridFS standard implemented within drivers will split files up into smaller chunks and store them in a `fs.chunks` collection irrespective of how big the file is.