# What's the maximum size for GridFS on MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

Basically I have a quite simple questions, but I was not able to find the answer in the MongoDB documentation or using Google.

What I want to know is, whether there is a upper limit of how big a MongoDB based GridFS may become?

(I know that the default maximum file size is 16 MByte, and that you can exceed this limit by using GridFS. But what is the upper limit for all files in GridFS?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB - Maximum file size using GridFS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16604875/mongodb-maximum-file-size-using-gridfs)

Comment: No, it's no duplicate, as my question is not about the maximum size of an individual file, but of the entire file system. The question you refer to is about the maximum size of an individual file instead.

Comment: Hmm, I guess. But, the answer to that question is "infinite" I'm pretty sure infinity * number of files will also equate to infinite ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MongoDB uses the operating system's mmapped IO as storage engine. The theoretical maximum, if there are no other limits imposed by implementation details, would be the amount of virtual memory your OS can assign to the mongod process. On a 32 bit OS, you will run into this limit very quickly. On windows for example, by default half the address space is reserved for the OS, so your mongod instance will stop accepting writes at a size of around 2 Gb

On a 64 bit OS, this theoretical maximum is quite a bit larger - 64 bits worth of it, in the order of millions of terabytes if I'm not mistaken. You will reach another limit before you reach this one.

EDIT:

This may no longer be true as of MongoDB 3.0. The WiredTiger storage engine works in a different way.

Comment: So in the end this means with GridFS I'll end up with the sum of the individual maximums of participating MongoDB instances, right?

Comment: That sounds right. Barring bugs I'm not aware of, in practice it will be your OS and hardware that limits the size: the maximum amount of virtual memory assignable to a process.

Comment: Just that I understand it right: The amount of virtual memory of all participating instances in sum, or the amount of virtual memory of a single instance (no matter how many instances are there)?

Comment: Each individual mongod instance should have this theoretical limit, but I don't see how you could reach it - do you have exabytes worth of data? Anyway, under any practical circumstances your OS will probably impose a lower limit.

Answer (score 1):

I think the limit is only in your hardware, mainly disk space.

Theorically with MongoDB you can store all documents you want. GridFS is only a system to save bigger documents in smaller chunks.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support this? I'd basically think (or let's say, assume) the same, but I'd like to read that somewhere in an official place ;-)

Comment: No. I have not. But I think that a database to store high amount of data will be useless with that limitation. There is no differences between store documents, or store chunks of documents. Maybe someone could give us a real example.