# Where is the best place to store photos uploaded by users on a forum

Tags: mongodb, file-upload

My website has a forum section and when they post/reply on the forum, they can upload an image as well. Where would be the best place to store these images, I expect to have to store about 100 images a day.

The website and forum is built using the MERN stack and so would I be better using gridfs or is this a bad idea? Is it better to store them elsewhere and then just reference them in mongodb.

This is the first time I've ever worked with image uploads and so I have no idea where to even start.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are storing 100 images per day. And I am assuming that may increase in future. You should store the images in `Aws S3`  or in the cloud of your choice.

Here are some articles that may help you make your choice :

[https://medium.com/@simonjcarr/mongodb-gridfs-vs-s3-storage-f5ba1ebcc490#:~:text=Since%20GridFS%20is%20part%20of,the%20limiting%20factor%20with%20Mongo](https://medium.com/@simonjcarr/mongodb-gridfs-vs-s3-storage-f5ba1ebcc490#:%7E:text=Since%20GridFS%20is%20part%20of,the%20limiting%20factor%20with%20Mongo).

[What's the maximum size for GridFS on MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21331141/whats-the-maximum-size-for-gridfs-on-mongodb)