# WiredTiger, GridFS and Mongodb uploading file and max file size

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs, wiredtiger

Three questions about WiredTiger storage and MongoDB.

1. I need to store (binary) files in the DB that may exceed 16MB size, now I read on WiredTiger site that the maximum file size is 512MB, but on Mongodb [insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/insert/#dbcmd.insert) method it says that the maximum size of all of the documents should be 16MB, so will I be able to store files that are larger then 16MB while using WiredTiger?
2. I need to use a complete file and not parts of it (like streaming parts of a video), is it possible to do with GridFS?
3. How can I insert and find files in the DB? I can't find a guide on how to do it with WiredTiger...

   Do I have to do it from the mongoshell or mongofiles? Is there a way to do it programmatically with node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) GridFS should be used for files larger than 16 MB:
[*GridFS is a specification for storing and retrieving files that exceed the BSON-document size limit of 16 MB.*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#gridfs)

EDIT:
Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16604875/mongodb-maximum-file-size-using-gridfs) for GridFS limits.

2) On insert query [*GridFS divides a file into chunks*. *When you query GridFS for a file, the driver will reassemble the chunks as needed.*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#gridfs)

3) Querying GridFS using WiredTiger or other engine (MMAPv1) is transparent for the user. Files can be queried using the driver methods, [info here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/tutorials/gridfs/streaming/).

Comment: In the API example for GridFS, they use a stream for the file, can I safely assume that it send a complete assembled file and not parts of it?

Comment: Of course yes, the driver handles that transparently for you.

Comment: where did u find document supporting you shouldn't store files less than 16Mb on gridfs??
It say's if your files are bigger than 16Mb you **SHOULD** use gridfs! but for less than that you **HAVE** the option to use collections!